# Conexión a base de datos mysql con python 3.5

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x

Estoy realizando mi primera aplicación con base de datos mysqldb en Python 3.5, utilizando MySQL Workbench para manipular y crear las tablas y los campos para mi base de datos. Al ejecutar el script en Python no genera ningún error, pero no continua el proceso de ingreso de datos a mi base de datos.

Tengo instalado el conector python(3.4) 2.1.6, hice el ensayo con el IDLE de python 3.4 y me da igual, me sigue trayendo el menú para elegir opciones cuando le doy cualquier número para continuar.

Este es mi código:

```
def Menu():
    #import MySQLdb
    import  os

    print("Estas en el Menu Pirncipal de Tienda")
    print("")
    print("1. Agregar Articulos")
    print("2. Modificar Articulos")
    print("3. Eliminar Articulos")
    print("4. Ver Articulos")
    print("5. Salir ")
    print("")
    try:
        OP=int(input("Introduce el numero de la Opcion deseada :"))
    except:
        print("Esto no es un numero por favor elija uno!!!!")
        print("")
    os.system('cls')
    Menu()

    if OP == 1:
        Agregar()
    elif OP == 2:
        Modificar()
    elif OP == 3:
        Eliminar()
    elif OP == 4:
        Ver()
    elif OP == 5:
        Salir()
    else:
        print("por favor digite un numero del menu!!!")
    Menu()

def Agregar():
    import MySQLdb.connections
    con = MySQLdb.connection.conect(user='root',password='j1i2s3t4',host='localhost', port=3307, database='bdarticulos')
    print("Estas en el Menu Agregar ")
    print("")

    name = input("Digite el nombre del Articulo")
    price = input("Digite el Precio del Articulo")
    os.system('cls')
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Productos(Nombre, Precio) values('"+name+"', '"+price+"')")
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    Menu()
Menu()
```

Esto lo que sucede al ejecutar el script:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]:

> C:\Python35\python.exe C:/Python35/CURSO-MYSQL/Tienda.py
>
> Estas en el Menu Pirncipal de Tienda
>
> 1. Agregar Articulos
> 2. Modificar Articulos
> 3. Eliminar Articulos
> 4. Ver Articulos
> 5. Salir
>
> Introduce el numero de la Opcion deseada :1 Estas en el Menu
>   Pirncipal de Tienda
>
> 1. Agregar Articulos
> 2. Modificar Articulos
> 3. Eliminar Articulos
> 4. Ver Articulos
> 5. Salir
>
> Introduce el numero de la Opcion deseada :5 Estas en el Menu
>   Pirncipal de Tienda
>
> 1. Agregar Articulos
> 2. Modificar Articulos
> 3. Eliminar Articulos
> 4. Ver Articulos
> 5. Salir
>
> Introduce el numero de la Opcion deseada :3 Estas en el Menu
>   Pirncipal de Tienda
>
> 1. Agregar Articulos
> 2. Modificar Articulos
> 3. Eliminar Articulos
> 4. Ver Articulos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error en la lógica de tu menú:

```
try:
    OP=int(input("Introduce el numero de la Opcion deseada :"))
except:
    print("Esto no es un numero por favor elija uno!!!!")
    print("")
os.system('cls')
Menu()
```

Llamas a `Menu` de nuevo nada más pedir el `input`, independientemente de que se genere o no una excepción. Solo deberias llamar a `Menu` si lo introducido no es un entero, por lo que debería estar dentro del bloque del `except` y no fuera como lo tienes. Lo mismo pasa con el `else` final. Tu función debería ser algo así:

```
def Menu():
    print("Estas en el Menu Pirncipal de Tienda")
    print("")
    print("1. Agregar Articulos")
    print("2. Modificar Articulos")
    print("3. Eliminar Articulos")
    print("4. Ver Articulos")
    print("5. Salir ")
    print("")
    try:
        OP=int(input("Introduce el numero de la Opcion deseada :"))
    except:
        os.system('cls')
        print("Esto no es un numero por favor elija uno!!!!")
        print("")
        Menu()

    if OP == 1:
        Agregar()
    elif OP == 2:
        Modificar()
    elif OP == 3:
        Eliminar()
    elif OP == 4:
        Ver()
    elif OP == 5:
        Salir()
    else:
        os.system('cls')
        print("por favor digite un numero del menu!!!")
        Menu()
```

Además de esto, no debes realizar los import dentro de la función, esto se hace al principio del script.

No obstante, deberias hacer el código iterativo en vez de recursivo:

```
import  os
import textwrap
import MySQLdb

def Menu():
    menu = textwrap.dedent('''\
                Estas en el Menu Principal de Tienda

                  1. Agregar Articulos
                  2. Modificar Articulos
                  3. Eliminar Articulos
                  4. Ver Articulos
                  5. Salir
                ''')
    while True:
        os.system('cls')
        print(menu)
        OP = input("Introduce el numero de la Opcion deseada: ")

        if not OP.isdigit():
            os.system('cls')
            print("Esto no es un numero por favor elija uno!!!!\n")        
        elif OP == '1':
            Agregar()
        elif OP == '2':
            Modificar()
        elif OP == '3':
            Eliminar()
        elif OP == '4':
            Ver()
        elif OP == '5':
            Salir()
            break
        else:
            os.system('cls')
            print("Por favor, digite un numero del menu!!!\n")


def Agregar():
    con = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',   # your host 
                          user='root',        # username
                          passwd='j1i2s3t4',  # password
                          db='bdarticulos')   # name of the database

    print("Estas en el Menu Agregar ")
    print("")

    name = input("Digite el nombre del Articulo")
    price = input("Digite el Precio del Articulo")
    os.system('cls')

    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO Productos(Nombre, Precio) VALUES(%s, %s)''', (name, price))
    con.commit()
    con.close()

Menu()
```

No tienes que llamar a `Menu` dentro de las otras funciones (`agregar`, `modificar`, `ver` y `eliminar`), al terminar su ejecución volverás a él.

Comment: entendida la configuracion de la funcion, pero no me quiere conectar a la base datos. pero me sigue generando este error al ejecutar el script:

Comment: Introduce el numero de la Opcion deseada: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python35/CURSO-MYSQL/ejemsqlyte3.py", line 54, in <module>
    Menu()
  File "C:/Python35/CURSO-MYSQL/ejemsqlyte3.py", line 25, in Menu
    Agregar()
  File "C:/Python35/CURSO-MYSQL/ejemsqlyte3.py", line 42, in Agregar
    con = MySQLdb.connection.conect(user='root',password='j1i2s3t4',host='localhost', port=3307, database='bdarticulos')
AttributeError: type object '_mysql.connection' has no attribute 'conect'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: al digitar la opcion 1 genera el anterior error

Comment: @Jsierra2017 he modificado el código del final de mi respuesta (la función Agregar y el import). Prueba a ver si te fucniona. el problema es que no podemos probar esto al no tener tu base de datos. Saludos.

Comment: return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 204, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)")

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: :\Python35\python.exe C:/Python35/CURSO-MYSQL/ejemp-mysql2.py
Estas en el Menu Principal de Tienda

  1. Agregar Articulos
  2. Modificar Articulos
  3. Eliminar Articulos
  4. Ver Articulos
  5. Salir

Introduce el numero de la Opcion deseada: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python35/CURSO-MYSQL/ejemp-mysql2.py", line 57, in <module>
    Menu()
  File "C:/Python35/CURSO-MYSQL/ejemp-mysql2.py", line 24, in Menu
    Agregar()
  File "C:/Python35/CURSO-MYSQL/ejemp-mysql2.py", line 43, in

Comment: ha sido buena la informacion pero llego al mismo punto como al comienzo, con su codigo me funciona igual, que el enviado con la pregunta, por que me esta generando los mismos errores.??? y no lograr continuar?

Comment: @Jsierra2017 ese error indica que la conexión ha sido rechazada por alguna razón, ¿tienes el proceso mysqld.exe funcionando? ¿Algún cortafuegos que pudiera bloquear?. Intenta cambiar localhost por 127.0.0.1. Mirate esta pregunta del sitio en inglés a ver si algo te funciona : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892689/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-localhost-10061-after-installation. El problema es que las causas pueden ser varias y no se deben al código en teoría sino a tu sistema.

Comment: return Connection(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: me esta generando errror en la carpeta __init__.py

Comment: perdon archivos y archivo connetions.py    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2) en la carpeta mysqldb en python/lib/site-packages

Comment: @Jsierra2017 "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)" como te he comentado este error se debe a que la conexión ha sido rechazada y suele indicar que el **servidor está mal configurado** o que el servicio está detenido. ¿Has probado a cambiar localhost por 127.0.0.1 como te comenté? ¿Tienes el servidor configurado para escuchar en el puerto por defecto (3306)? ¿esta el puerto TCP 3306 (si es el que usas ) habilitado en el firewall?

Comment: ok solucionado el problema una coma al final del port=3307, era lo que me estaba generando el problema de conexion, nuevamente gracias por su tiempo. asi es como se aprende de los errores.

Comment: @Jsierra2017 de nada y si, así se aprende a programar, programando y cometiendo errores, no hay otro camino. Otra cosa, llevas varias preguntas en el sitio, deberias considerar aceptar aquellas respuestas que solucionaran tu problema, si las hay, para ayudar a otros usuarios con tu mismo problema a identificarlas y, de paso, ganas alguna reputación para poder usar el chat por ejemplo. Mirate: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas. Esta conversación tan extensa no deberiamos haberla tenido en comentarios si no en el chat.  Saludos.

Comment: correcto, de todas formas gracias por tu tiempo. y atendere tus sugerencias. hasta la proxima

Answer (score 1):

Tal como está el codigo, nunca llega a ejecutarse la parte en la que se actualiza la base de datos.

Tu código básicamente hace ésto:

```
def Menu():
  ... # código que muestra el menú
  ... # introduce una opción
  Menu()
  ... # control de opciones
  Menu()  # a este Menu nunca se llega
```

Lo que viene a ser que estás *"recursivamente"* invocando una y otra vez la función `Menu` sin hacer otra cosa, sin llegar nunca a la parte en la que se invocan la demás funciones.

Nunca es bueno usar funciones recursivas de modo descontrolado como estás haciendo. Toda función recursiva debería tener algún modo de finalizar o de lo contrario se llenará el stack de llamadas y acabará en error.

Sin hacer mucho cambio, cambia tu función `Menu` a un bucle:

```
def Menu():
    import  os

    OP = 0

    while (OP != 5):
        print("Estas en el Menu Pirncipal de Tienda")
        print("")
        print("1. Agregar Articulos")
        print("2. Modificar Articulos")
        print("3. Eliminar Articulos")
        print("4. Ver Articulos")
        print("5. Salir ")
        print("")
        try:
            OP=int(input("Introduce el numero de la Opcion deseada :"))
        except:
            print("Esto no es un numero por favor elija uno!!!!")
            print("")
        os.system('cls')

        if OP == 1:
            Agregar()
        elif OP == 2:
            Modificar()
        elif OP == 3:
            Eliminar()
        elif OP == 4:
            Ver()
        elif OP == 5:
            Salir()
        else:
            print("por favor digite un numero del menu!!!")
```

Comment: ok, si tienes razon, esa opcion de llamar al menu varias veces de por si me estaba generando error al ejecutar el script.

Comment: si pero sigue generando error al ejecutar la funcion agregar, en la conexion a la base de datos, y la opcion menu al final del codigo.

Comment: Introduce el numero de la Opcion deseada :1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python35/CURSO-MYSQL/ejemp-mysql2.py", line 49, in <module>
    Menu()
  File "C:/Python35/CURSO-MYSQL/ejemp-mysql2.py", line 23, in Menu
    Agregar()
  File "C:/Python35/CURSO-MYSQL/ejemp-mysql2.py", line 37, in Agregar
    con = MySQLdb.connection.conect(user='root',password='j1i2s3t4',host='localhost', port=3307, database='bdarticulos')
AttributeError: type object '_mysql.connection' has no attribute 'conect'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: con la opcion 1 genera el anterior error

Comment: llegamos como al comienzo el codigo me genera la misma ejecucion y los mismos errores???

Comment: ok solucianado gracias una coma estaba generando mi problema de conexion gracias.